# Getting an array from a json object into a list

Tags: python, json

I have the following code:

```
y=list()
y.extend(args.get("vars"))
y.extend({("var_last","2")})
print(y)
```

While args supposed to look like:

```
args = {
    .
    .
    .
"vars": [
 {
 "name": "str"
  "value": "str"
 }]
 }
```

However I get:
`{{O, b, j, c, t, o, b, j, e, c, t} {("last_var", "2")}}`

Instead of:
`{{"Str","str"},{("last_var", "2")}}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is {O, b, j, c, t, o, b, j, e, c, t}

Comment: `y` is a list. Why do you expect `print(y)` to tell you it's a set?

Answer (score 0):

The `extends` function of a list extends the list by appending all the items from the iterable.
I think you're looking for the `append` function for a Python list.

```
y=list()
y.append(args.get("vars"))
y.append({("var_last","2")})
print(y)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: That doesn't work too, tried different variations with loads and dumps functions, but still can't understand what is the right order to do all of them

Comment: May you add an example of what args contains?

Comment: When I put append it just puts [[object object],("last_var","2")]

Comment: I did put the structure of the args in the question